# dynamic hide/show based on ajax

Tags: jquery

I currently have a dynamic array of ip addresses and want to show (if ip is active) and hide (if the ip is inactive). I have implemented the below solution but wondering if there is a better way..

data file is in JSON format and is updated every second, i am using jquery to get the contents of the JSON file and based on the values i want to show/hide the ip address and the corresponding device names(stored in IP_Address array)

```
var IP_Address = new Array();
for (i=0;i<70;i++){ IP_Address["10.1.1."+i]="other-devices";}
IP_Address["10.1.1.1"]="known-device-1";
IP_Address["10.1.1.16"]="known-device-2";
IP_Address["10.1.1.37"]="known-device-3";
IP_Address["10.1.1.38"]="known-device-4";
IP_Address["10.1.1.45"]="known-device-5";
IP_Address["10.1.1.46"]="known-device-6";
IP_Address["10.1.1.47"]="known-device-7";
IP_Address["10.1.1.49"]="known-device-8";
IP_Address["blank"]="";
```

JSON data is stored into an array (data) and the values can be assessed as below

```
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    if(data[i].dl>0){
        $("#jq"+i).html(IP_Address[data[i].ip]);}
    else if(data[i].dl ==0 ){
        $("#jq"+i).html(IP_Address["blank"]);}
}
```

in the html section...

```
<span id="jq1"></span>
<span id="jq2"></span>
<span id="jq3"></span>
<span id="jq4"></span>
<span id="jq5"></span>
<span id="jq6"></span>
<span id="jq7"></span>
<span id="jq8"></span>
<span id="jq9"></span>
<span id="jq10"></span>
<span id="jq11"></span>
<span id="jq12"></span>
<span id="jq13"></span>
<span id="jq14"></span>
<span id="jq15"></span>
<span id="jq16"></span>
<span id="jq17"></span>
<span id="jq18"></span>
<span id="jq19"></span>
<span id="jq20"></span>
```

Comment: This is a pretty vague question (well, there isn't even really a question) and it will be tremendously difficult to provide any insight without further details.

Comment: Why have a container for every possible device?  Why not create (and remove) the spans on the fly as you need them?

Comment: @Kevin P any example on how to create dynamic containers?

Comment: @Demian Brecht  all i want to do is show the active devices (based on the array values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this should help you

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { 
    setInterval(        
        function (){                

        var arr = new Array();

        for(var i=1;i<=5; i++){
           arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
        }           

        $('.sh').each(function (){
            if(arr.indexOf(Math.floor($(this).attr('id').replace('jq', ''))) > -1){
              $(this).show();
            }
            else{                         
              $(this).hide();
            }
        })
    }, 2000);
})

</script>
<span id="jq1" class="sh">1</span>
<span id="jq2" class="sh">2</span>
<span id="jq3" class="sh">3</span>
<span id="jq4" class="sh">4</span>
<span id="jq5" class="sh">5</span>
<span id="jq6" class="sh">6</span>
<span id="jq7" class="sh">7</span>
<span id="jq8" class="sh">8</span>
<span id="jq9" class="sh">9</span>
<span id="jq10" class="sh">10</span>
<span id="jq11" class="sh">11</span>
<span id="jq12" class="sh">12</span>
<span id="jq13" class="sh">13</span>
<span id="jq14" class="sh">14</span>
<span id="jq15" class="sh">15</span>
<span id="jq16" class="sh">16</span>
<span id="jq17" class="sh">17</span>
<span id="jq18" class="sh">18</span>
<span id="jq19" class="sh">19</span>
<span id="jq20" class="sh">20</span>
```

On [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ASr83/1/).

**PS**:: if somebody knows how to check for a value in array then please, help me improve my answer.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(4) > -1` - check for a value in array using a simple indexOf.